# Generation of high electrostatic voltage

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, voltage, conductors

I need to generate a 1000 volt electrostatic charge. How can I do this? I don't have a Van de Graaff generator. What are some practical suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

This is simple, and done all the time in high-powered *vacuum tube circuits* (audio amplifiers and RF amplifiers).

You obtain a *step-up transformer* which takes the mains voltage up to a high voltage, send it through a diode rectifier, and then filter the resulting pulsating DC to obtain a smooth, constant high voltage DC source.

All the components needed to accomplish this are readily available on-line, and if you post this question on the electronics stack exchange you can obtain the formulas for selecting the *step-up ratio* of the transformer to obtain exactly the output voltage you desire.

But Aniket!!! please note that such voltages are DEADLY and your circuit should be FUSED and WELL-INSULATED to avoid death and destruction!

Comment: I need to produce high voltage so that i can bring electrostatic induction effect on other conductor, so what will be the possible practical ways to produce that voltage so that i could induce charges on another conductor. Can we think of placing a thin conductor between parallel plates of capacitor(of high voltage capacitor) and induce positive and negative charges on either side? How practical this idea could be?

Comment: I suggest you post this question on the engineering stack exchange! best regards, Niels